# Is it true that for both React or Angular, they are also both "convention over configuration"?

Tags: angularjs, conventions, reactjs

In the Ruby on Rails communication, it is often said that RoR is "convention over configuration".

Can you say for React / Redux / Flux and AngularJS, Angular2, they are also "convention over configuration"?

---

Some details: the reason is, engineers probably do things in quite standard, or convention ways, such as

```
// in index.js:

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
  <App />
</Provider>

// in the container file:

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    dataList: state.data
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DataList);
```

and you usually won't tweak or change these conventions. (I just hope no interviewers will ask me to recite these lines verbatim at interviews... as whether you memorize these lines, do they make you a better programmer? The concepts can be important, but how these lines are verbatim, what is so good about memorizing them?)

Comment: So how does your example relate to convention over configuration? The code you posted looks pretty explicit and not convention based to me.

Comment: I'd say that uppercase *tag = directive, lowercase tag = html* counts as convention in React.

Comment: that's because it is how it wires up the state to props, and the action creators to the props, and it is all conventions.

Answer (score 1):

No, you've misunderstood convention over configuration.

The idea of convention over configuration is that you should not have to explicitly configure the framework. Instead, conventions are automatically applied.

Take for example:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DataList);
```

React makes you explicitly include this code. If React followed convention over configuration, it would assume that you wanted to do this as soon as you defined a mapStateToProps function and automatically do it for you.

So the point isn't that there is a standard convention. Convention over configuration is when the convention is automatic, not explicit in code.

Comment: but will you write something other than `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DataList);`? If you will not, what is the difference between it automatically add it for you, or you add it yourself?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 your question doesn't make any sense. Surely you understand the difference between the computer doing something for you and you having to do it yourself.

Comment: It doesn't automatically do it for you. In convention over configuration, it's not even needed, because it's implied

Comment: My main concern is "it is more of a convention" vs "freestyle". Whether the computer "automatically does it for you", is not of a main concern here. So maybe the name is not "convention over configuration" but "convention over free style programming". My focus is the "convention" part, not whether something is done "automatically".

Comment: @RMalke, what's the difference between automatic and implied?

Comment: @太極者無極而生, you don't seem to have a coherent question. You know that there is a lot of code that follows a standard convention in React. So I have no clue what your question is trying to ask, if not about "configuration over convention"

Comment: @WinstonEwert I agree with the answer. Automatic would be code generation, where a framework/tools creates the code for you. Implied is, in the absence of code it works in the default behaviour.

Comment: I felt the similarity between RoR and React. If we use what is on Wikipedia: "Convention over configuration (also known as *coding by convention*) is a software design paradigm used by software frameworks that attempt to decrease the number of decisions that a developer using the framework is required to make without necessarily losing flexibility." It does seem RoR and React both are "coding by convention"

Comment: @RMalke, ok, that seems an insignificant implementation detail to me.

Comment: @太極者無極而生, yes, there is some sort of similarity there. But no, convention over configuration refers specifically to the case where it is automatic. It is incorrect to use the term to describe the react/redux style.

Comment: @WinstonEwert then from your perspective, do both RoR and React/Redux have the characteristics of "coding by convention"?

Comment: @太極者無極而生, no coding by convention is just another name for convention over configuration. The name coding by convention refers to the way that coding is replaced by convention.